# Regex search-and-replace to get rid of a line break

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with the following text. There is a `line break` for many of the rows in this file.

I need to use backspace and join with the previous line text for the line which starts with `your`

```
            1023456;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
            2345678;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
            4567891;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for
             your account;BR
            2345678;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
            1023456;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
            4567891;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for
             your account;BR
            4567891;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for
             your account;BR
```

The desired result

```
              1023456;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
              2345678;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
              4567891;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
              2345678;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
              1023456;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
              4567891;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
              4567891;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
```

I have used `notepad++` macro to do this but the results was a single line of text with all the 1000 lines in the file.

ANy help would be appreciated

Comment: Try it like this [`(?<=for)\s+(?=your)`](https://regex101.com/r/QSvjFy/1) and replace with a whitespace

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use a regex, I'd approach it by capturing all instances of 'for' with a newline or carriage return following it and replace these with 'for '.

For example, if with I were to approach your problem in JavaScript I would use the following:

```
var str = `1023456;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
            2345678;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
            4567891;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for
             your account;BR
            2345678;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
            1023456;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
            4567891;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for
             your account;BR
            4567891;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for
             your account;BR`;

var regex = /(for(\n|\r))/gm;

var res = str.replace(regex, 'for ');
```

This would result in:

```
1023456;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
2345678;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
4567891;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
2345678;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
1023456;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
4567891;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
4567891;jjdss.D.djDJ;2345;for your account;BR
```

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gm96eud1/1/) to illustrate this.

If you are looking to get some more experience in regex there are some great answers out there to help you along, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions?rq=1) which does a good job of explaining them as well as linking to some useful resources.